Help me calculate the triple summation
Problem
We consider
$$
\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_{i\nu}-\xi_i)(x_{j\nu}-\xi_j) = \sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_{i\nu}-\bar{x}_i)(x_{j\nu}-\bar{x}_j) - 2n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j),
$$
where $\bar{x}_i := \frac{1}{n} (x_{i1} + \cdots + x_{in}),\ i = 1,\ldots , k$
My calculate
\begin{align}
\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_{i\nu}-\xi_i)(x_{j\nu}-\xi_j) &=
\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}\{(x_{i\nu}-\bar{x}_i)+(\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)\}\{(x_{j\nu}-\bar{x}_j)+(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j)\}\\ &=
\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (x_{i\nu}-\bar{x}_i)(x_{j\nu}-\bar{x}_j)
+ \underbrace{\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (x_{i\nu}-\bar{x}_i)(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j)}_{=0}
+ \underbrace{\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)(x_{j\nu}-\bar{x}_j)}_{=0}
+ \sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j)\\ &=
\sum_{\nu=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (x_{i\nu}-\bar{x}_i)(x_{j\nu}-\bar{x}_j)
+ n\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j)
\end{align}
What is wrong?

It's very minor but you seem to have forgotten the $a_{ij}$s after the second line.

You haven't done anything wrong besides forgetting the $a_{ij}$s along the calculation.
The terms you've underlined are indeed $0$ since summing w.r.t $\nu$ makes $n\overline{x}_i - n\overline{x}_i= 0$ appear, and you do have $+n$ instead of $-2n$ in front of the last sum but there is nothing you could do to change that, unless you'd have a particular problem in which you'd know, either as an assumption or as a consequence of some assumptions, that: $$\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k (\bar{x}_i-\xi_i)(\bar{x}_j-\xi_j) = 0$$
Moreover, you can always check what happens with small $n$s in cases like this where you're unsure what's true or not. Here, for $n = 1$, we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_{i}-\xi_i)(x_{j}-\xi_j) = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_i-x_i)(x_j-x_j)}_{=\,0} + \underbrace{1}_{\text{not -2 !}}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}(x_i-\xi_i)(x_j-\xi_j)$$
where the $x_i$s are both the $x_{i\nu}$s and the $\overline{x}_i$s.
